# Using c++11 unordered_map types on mac os x

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, unordered-map

I'm on MAC OS X 10.8.4 and have installed gcc by downloading XCode and the command line tools package. Here is my gcc:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

I'm trying to use the new unordered_map from the tr1 namespace:

```
using namespace std;
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

template<class T>
class A 
{
    tr1::unordered_map<T, int> * mymap;
    .....
    // key is of type T and value is of type int
    mymap->at(key) = value;
}
```

However, the line where I'm accessing the map element using `at` is not compiling. I'm getting the following error:

```
error: 'class std::tr1::unordered_map<int, int, std::tr1::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >, false>' has no member named 'at'
```

I don't quite understand this since the C++ reference does include a function called `at` to access individual elements of the map. I tried to look into the header files containing the map declaration (on my system it is at `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/unordered_map`) and surprisingly enough, it does not contain a member named `at`.

I understand that older compilers might not be supporting new c++11 libraries in the `std` namespace, but I've been able to use some of the other new libraries from `tr1` namespace. In fact, I can use other functions of `unordered_map` like `find`, `insert` etc. Only the member `at` is missing.

How can I get this compiled? Should I upgrade to a newer compiler? I don't see the new compilers available for mac os x readily. Should I build it from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your gcc version is too low. Besides, maybe you should install clang instead since Apple is the force behind it.

When you have upgraded to the latest version, you should not use `tr1` anymore. `tr1` is the draft for C++11 and is deprecated now.

Comment: TR1 is **not** deprecated, nor is it a draft of anything. At the time it was written it was information about possible future directions for the C++ standard library, and stood on its own. The need for implementations of TR1 is much less now, as standard library implementations catch up with the C++11 standard. Which doesn't mean that the advice here is wrong: unless you have to have backward compatibility, if your compiler supports C++11 you should probably use that.

Answer (score 4):

1) `unordered_map` is a form of `map` containter, use `unordered_map::find(KeyType key)` instead, which returns `unordered_map::iterator`, essentially pointer to`std::pair< KeyType, ValueType >`.

Or you can use `unordered_map::operator[](KeyType key)` to get access to element pointed by the `key` variable. Note that it will create new element in case it doesn't exist yet.

See [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) for more info.

2) Use newer GCC (at least 4.7) with `-std=c++11` option, and you will get standardized `std::unordered_map` instead of `tr1::unordered_map`